# CSS, HTML Overlay background with transparency

Tags: html, css, overlay

I'm banging my head against this since some time:

[image: Striped background example]

I'll try to give best description to this problem:

On the image you see a heading (`h2` for example). You see it on the background with stripes (body background). What I want to achieve is to have this heading with the background of the gray stripes (marked in blue border on the image), but where the text is I don't want to have this background, but the background of the body (marked in red border).

My only solution to this was:

```
<h1><span>Our Solutions</span></h1>
```

```css
h1
{
  background: url(stripes.png);
}
h1 span
{
  background: url(body-stripes.png)
}
```

But there is a problem with matching the stripes from heading with those from body.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: show us your code kroma.......with demo

Comment: You need to find a fixed known point where you can anchor them both in sync. Maybe position both backgrounds to the right edge of the page and then tile them both from that spot.

Comment: @krona now used to this i thing u want to this http://tinkerbin.com/DsbMShGb

Comment: http://tinkerbin.com/x6RxlLsK

You see the problem here if you do screenshot and zoom it, you will see that stripes does not match...

Problem is heading will be always in different placese, many of them on the page, also some of them in 1/3 column floated right and so... im hopeless with this

Comment: @kroma see this one are you loooking like this :- http://tinkerbin.com/x7yY0arN

Comment: or you can come here for discuss further things :- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15567/front-end-developer

Comment: Thanks for reply but here as you posted
http://tinkerbin.com/x7yY0arN

I dont see text area have different stipes (inherited from body)

Comment: you can see my updated answer i have given two links please check below.....

Answer (score 1):

I would put a wrapper around the `H1` instead, but the key to matching up the stripes is to use background positioning.

```
<div id='bar'><h1>Our Solutions</h1></div>
```

```css
#bar
{
  width:100%;
  background: url(stripes.png);
}
h1{
  display: inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: url(body-stripes.png);
  background-position: -4px 0px;
}
```

Then change "-4px" 1 pixel at a time until the stripes match up.  In this example, "-4px" moves the background image 4 pixels to the left.

Comment: You see the problem here if you do screenshot and zoom it, you will see that stripes does not match... Problem is heading will be always in different placese, many of them on the page, also some of them in 1/3 column floated right and so... im hopeless with this

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.  Is the page online somewhere so we can see it?

Comment: p.s.  The only way you will ever get the stripes to match is by specifying the background position.  You have to adjust the "-4px" to the correct amount of pixels until it lines up.